# Why netbeans is hanging everytime it is trying to fetch files from a remote php site using ftp?

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp

Hi
I'm very new to Netbeans and I want to create a project for a remote PHP site. every time netbeans tries to fetch files from remote site using ftp, after fetching some files it hangs and I should close IDE completely cause it is not responsive anymore! I'm using version 7.0 beta 2.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

hmmm.. mybe Your computer does not meet the system requirements...
such as your ram or the bandwith,...

Comment: it is not like that it is not working at all; it fetches some files but suddenly hangs, the progress bar still showing somethings going on but it is not so (I know that from output window) the strange thing is it always hangs on the same command which is "opening binary mode..." on an empty folder. I should mention ftp server is proftpd on centos with xampp

Comment: As I tested more and more, now I've found out the problem is with empty directories! it seems netbeans ftp client got problems with downloading empty directories!

Answer (score 0):

As this is a beta version it might have bugs. Report your's to the NetBeans BugZilla: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html